# Hyperledger-Composer: Getting "access denied" when pinging network admin card

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Im using Hyperledger Composer over Hyperledger Fabric to deploy a **.bna** file. The problem comes when creating **networkAdmin** cards for the different organizations, they are not able to access the network.

## Background

The project structure is as follows:

- Organizations:

  - exporter01 with one peer and one CA
  - maritimeAgency01 with one peer and one CA
  - terminal01 with one peer and one CA
  - terrestrialTransport01 with one peer and one CA

The steps towards the problem are as follows:

1. Create the **PeerAdmin** card using the admin **certificate** and **privateKey** files under **/msp/keystore/** for every organization
2. Installed the network archive using `composer network install ...` for every organization peer using the **PeerAdmin** card
3. Requested identities for every networkAdmin specified on the `composer network start ...` command (one for every org)
4. Started the network for all peers using
   `composer network start \
   --card PeerAdmin@$NETWORK_NAME-exporter01 \
   --networkName $NETWORK_NAME \
   --networkVersion $NETWORK_VERSION \
   -o endorsementPolicyFile=./endorsement-policy.json \
   -A exporter01 \
   -C $TMP_BASEDIR/exporter01/admin-pub.pem \
   -A maritimeAgency01 \
   -C $TMP_BASEDIR/maritimeAgency01/admin-pub.pem \
   -A terminal01 \
   -C $TMP_BASEDIR/terminal01/admin-pub.pem \
   -A terrestrialTransport01 \
   -C $TMP_BASEDIR/terrestrialTransport01/admin-pub.pem`

## Problem

After using `composer card create ...` with the following

- **connectionProfile.json** (the same used to create the **PeerAdmin** card)
- user: the same as the `-A` flag in the `composer network start ...`
- certificate: the same as the `-C` flag in the `composer network start ...`
- privateKey: the corresponding to the certificate generated by `composer identity request ...`

And importing it with `composer card import ...` the card is successfully imported. **But** when using `composer network ping -c <created networkAdmin card>` the command fails with the following message

`Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Exporter01MSP]`

Any ideas why could this be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: when you use `composer card list` does it show all the cards that you're expecting?

Comment: Yes! It shows all the **PeerAdmin** cards and **networkAdmin** cards.

Comment: Firstly, I would check at a FABRIC level that you can deploy/test sample chaincode eg [sample FABRIC marbles](https://github.com/asararatnakar/fabric_v1_Chaincode_instructions/blob/master/how-to-exec-marble-chaincode.md)  can be invoked / queried so that you know all the peers have joined the FABRIC network and there are no errors - have you done any tests of your Fabric n/w ? 2. As for Composer - in your task list, you would have had to do '4.' (identity request, using the right PeerAdmin card for the respective organisations) before you did '3.'  (above)

Comment: 3. Also - I am wondering how soon you did the ping after `composer network start` (a chaincode container is being built and can take time by the time the 'dust settles') - the error is a little generic

Comment: I've edited the task list. Indeed i was requesting the identities before the network start.
Also, i was able to test the sample chaincode at a Fabric level. I think the problem is composer-related since it's the networkAdmin card that is bein rejected

Comment: I've tried the ping immediately after and also after some hours. Neither worked. YES! The error is too generic.

Comment: This is a fabric level error and hasn't even got as far as communicating with the business network. You need to check your peer logs to see exactly why access is being denied with the identity you are trying to use. It could be a mistake in the way you have configured your genesis block and channel transaction when you think you have given the correct policy permissions or you are trying with an identity from that MSP which hasn't been given authority on the channel

Comment: @JoseTomas can you also post what Fabric version / Composer version you're using?

Comment: Checking the peer logs found this error message `Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity` and also this one `WARN 1b16 [channel: mychannel] Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 172.18.0.1:54746: Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [mychannel] with policy [/Channel/Application/Readers]: [Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining]`

Comment: I'm using Composer v0.19.9 and Fabric 1.1

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your CA setup such that the identity it generates isn't recognised by your fabric network setup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### After two weeks found the error. Logging it here for the community.

It was a Hyperledger-Fabric configuration error.

When using multiple CA's (one for each org) you must add the certificates to the orderer docker container as an env variable `ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS` or any identity issued by those CA's won't be able to connect.

Found the solution in the following [fabric-sample Repo](https://github.com/sstone1/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose.yaml) line 55. Don't forget to link the volumes (lines 63-64).