# Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [composerchannel] creator org

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Trying to add a new organisation from a separate host.(Modifying steps from ./eyfn.sh when necessary).

Managed to create and import network admin card using Hyperledger Composer. (https://medium.com/@mahoney_33893/hyperledger-composer-adding-another-organization-to-an-existing-running-multi-organization-fff5c8104a82).

However when pinging the network I got:

Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [composerchannel] creator org [Org3MSP]

Upon getting the logs from peer I got 
-Principal deserialization failure (MSP Org3MSP is unknown) for identity
-[channel: composerchannel] Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 10.0.1.6:48262: Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [composerchannel] with policy [/Channel/Application/Readers]: [Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining]

My problem is actually similar to that of [Hyperledger-Composer: Getting "access denied" when pinging network admin card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329602/hyperledger-composer-getting-access-denied-when-pinging-network-admin-card).

The solution did mention to include msp files of my new org into volumes of the orderer which I did as

```
docker cp msp <containername>:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com
```

My first organisation was set up using the default ./startFabric.sh

Take note that im not using TLS for the time being.

The error still persist though and Im wondering why. I do however suspect that the way im giving msp to the orderer is somehow wrong. or Im putting it in a wrong file.

Comment: i suspect that my solo orderer is not able to read my cryto material from the peer in the newly added organization.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will need to migrate from Composer to other framework.
Hundreds of devs are taking is using [Convector](https://covalentx.com/convector). Convector is a Hyperledger Labs project that was created before Hyperledger Composer was deprecated but that looks similar to developers. It follows a model controller pattern (similar to Composer assets and transactions) however it compiles natively to Fabric code and does not create a runtime.